# Using java class in avro schema

Tags: java, avro

Is there a way to import java class in avro. I am trying to be able to use a variable of a specified java class. I dont see anything in the avro documentation so wanted to see if any one found a work around for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can not include any language specific files in an avro idl or schema, since they should be language independent in order to emit the language specific content. For instance a single avro schema can produce both java and c++ files.